# Evaluating XQuery/XPath expressions from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a table that contains XQuery expressions. I'd like to evaluate the expression from each row for a given XML data structure. I'm trying this.

```
DECLARE @somexml xml
SET @somexml = '<root><nodeA>true</nodeA><nodeB>false</nodeB></root>'

SELECT
    @somexml.query('sql:column("af.Expression")' ) AS Fee,
    [af].Expression 
FROM 
    [AerialFees] af
```

The `Expression` column contains values of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` such as:
- `xs:boolean(/root[1]/nodeA[1])`

When executing this `SELECT` the expressions don't get evaluated, instead the expression itself is returned (btw, of type XML)

```
Fee                        Expression
==================================================
xs:boolean(/root[1]/nodeA[1])    xs:boolean(/root[1]/nodeA[1])
```

If a replace `@somexml.query('sql:column("af.Expression")' )` with the actual expression `@somexml.query('xs:boolean(/root[1]/nodeA[1])' )` the expression gets correctly evaluated.

But how can I get the above to work?

Comment: My bad, forgot the last tag

Comment: You could use the new, `<xsl:evaluate>` instruction of XSLT 3.0 (not XQuery). See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the query dynamically something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @somexml XML
SET @somexml = '<root><nodeA>true</nodeA><nodeB>false</nodeB></root>'

DECLARE @Fees Table
(
    RowNum int,
    Expression nvarchar(max)
)   

INSERT INTO @Fees
SELECT 
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY af.idAerialFee),
    [af].Expression 
FROM 
    [AerialFee] af 

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM @Fees)

DECLARE @Iter INT
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM @Fees)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN
    -- Get XQuery
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @somexml.query(''' + af.Expression + ''') AS Fee'
    FROM @Fees af
    WHERE RowNum = @Iter

    -- Evaluate XQuery
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@somexml xml', @somexml

    -- Get next rows number
    SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END
```

I know of no other way to provide the XPath expression to a query in SQL Server.

You could try to add the expression directly:

```
select @somexml.query(af.Expression)
from AerialFees as af
```

But that gives you the error message

```
Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal.
```

Or you could try to use `sql:column` (as you did) but that just returns the value in the column. It does not try to evaluate the expression.

`xsl:evaluate` as suggested by [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234363/evaluating-xquery-xpath-expressions-from-table/14236391#comment19751672_14234363) is not supported in [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx).

Comment: Well, actually I wanted to avoid Dynamic SQL. Is there no other way. If not, why so? I can't really think of a reason.

Comment: @Szymonides I updated with a bit more info on what one might try. **Why** it is like this I can only speculate. The XPath expression used is interpreted when the query plan is created so the value has to be known before it is time to actually execute the query.

Comment: `AerialFees` contains more than one row, but `@SQL` contains only the last entry.

Comment: @Szymonides Yes, that would be a problem when building the query dynamically. Not impossible (depending on what you want to do) but more complicated.